# Filtering data among multiple array type elements

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Dataframe schema:

```
root
 |-- ID: decimal(15,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- COL1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- COL2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- COL3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Sample data

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|         COL1       |        COL2        |              COL3  |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[A, B, C, A]        |[101, 102, 103, 104]|[P, Q, R, S]        |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to apply nested conditions on array elements.

For example,

**Find `COL3` elements where `COL1` elements are A and `COL2` elements are even.**

Expected Output : [S]

---

I looked at various functions. For e.g. - [array_position](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_position) but it returns only the first occurrence.

Is there any straightforward way or I have to explode arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your condition applies to array elements with the same index, it is possible to [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) arrays with lambda functions in SQL since Spark 2.4.0, but this is still not exposed via the other language APIs and you need to use `expr()`. You simply zip the three arrays and then filter the resulting array of structs:

```
scala> df.show()
+---+------------+--------------------+------------+
| ID|        COL1|                COL2|        COL3|
+---+------------+--------------------+------------+
|  1|[A, B, C, A]|[101, 102, 103, 104]|[P, Q, R, S]|
+---+------------+--------------------+------------+

scala> df.select($"ID", expr(s"""
     | filter(
     |   arrays_zip(COL1, COL2, COL3),
     |   e -> e.COL1 == "A" AND CAST(e.COL2 AS integer) % 2 == 0
     | ).COL3 AS result
     | """)).show()
+---+------+
| ID|result|
+---+------+
|  1|   [S]|
+---+------+
```

Since this uses `expr()` to supply an SQL expression as a column, it also works with PySpark:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
>>> df.select(df.ID, expr("""
...   filter(
...     arrays_zip(COL1, COL2, COL3),
...     e -> e.COL1 == "A" AND CAST(e.COL2 AS integer) % 2 == 0
...   ).COL3 AS result
... """)).show()
+---+------+
| ID|result|
+---+------+
|  1|   [S]|
+---+------+
```